# Opening an url without browser entering foreground in shell script

Tags: shell

I have an shell script which opens hundreds of php urls. I´m very new to shell scripts. So my simple approach would be:

```
open http://www.pathtofile.com/phpscript.php
```

The url then gets opened with my browser but it´s pushing my browser to foreground so it blocks everything. I cannot use my laptop afterwards actually. How can I run the scripts in some kind of "background-mode"?

Comment: add an `&` after your command, that will run the command in the background

Comment: @ryekayo The problem is the browser window coming to the foreground not the `open` call being run in the foreground (as it likely returns almost immediately).

Comment: What do you mean it "blocks everything" and you "cannot use [your] laptop afterwards"? Do you just mean opening up that many windows makes your computer very slow or your window manager unhappy? Because neither running "in the backround" or getting the windows not to come to the front will help with either of those problems.

Comment: Hmm ok, im assuming this will be a horse of a different color then lol :)

Comment: With every opening command my browser pops up. When I minimize it and the next opening command is beeing executed it pops up again. The browser needs to be minimized. Because e.g. I am working on sth on a different programm then the script is executed as a cronjob and the browser is poping up. Every single time!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script in the background with:

```
path_to_the_script &
```

If script is in the current directory:

```
./script &
```

Comment: Doesn´t work. Im running the script in Terminal on OSX. The browser still pops up.

Comment: Then running it at background wasn't the solution to begin with

Comment: So I ended up using a different approach. I call the scripts with an other php script using curl. Simple.